# Does .NET 7 MAUI Blazor Windows App work with Native AOT?

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

I am currently developing an app with Avalonia on .NET 7 and I was curious to see if I could move to MAUI Blazor as it'd improve my productivity. I do not plan to release the app on anything but desktop platforms, and even then I may keep it to Windows.

It is important to me to have Native AOT. I got this working with Avalonia by adding the following to my csproj:

```xml
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>
    <TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>
    <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
    <OptimizationPreference>Speed</OptimizationPreference>
    <EnableTrimAnalyzer>true</EnableTrimAnalyzer>
```

I installed the latest MAUI and created the default MAUI Blazor project in VS. I've attempted to apply the same or similar csproj settings, starting with just `<PublishAot>` and each step of the way the commandline publish has spit out errors. I cannot currently get it to work.

How can I get the default start up project to publish to native AOT?

Comment: Native AOT deployment have some limitations. You can check this doc about [Limitations in the .NET Native AOT deployment model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net8plus%2Cwindows#limitations-of-native-aot-deployment).